# Why doesn't spotlight return this file?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, file

I am on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3. I created a file with Python but when I search for its name inside Spotlight (or Finder), it's not there. When I `os.getcwd()` and manually follow its path, it is where it should be.

[image: path]

Why is this happening? What am I missing? Btw in order to manually find it, I turned on the hidden files visibility with (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.⇧</kbd>).

Edit: Assuming it has something to do with the fact it's inside hidden folders, is there a way to make Spotlight or Finder also return these files, or another way to search them by name (third party app maybe)?

Comment: Have you searched all existing answers on this site that cover this situation?  Several exist already and they have accepted answers.  You can [edit] your question to include what solutions you tried and any errors you received.

Comment: I use Find any File.  Uses an fast file find api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [EasyFind (Freeware)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12). It will search through all subfolders including hidden folders.

[image]